How can I track which fields have been edited in Netsuite when syncing NetSuite sales orders to Salesforce?
I'm working on a project where I need to sync sales orders between NetSuite and Salesforce. Specifically, I'm trying to track which fields have been updated in NetSuite and ensure these changes are accurately reflected in Salesforce.
I have a User Event script in NetSuite that triggers when a sales order is edited. This script updates the corresponding Salesforce order. However, I'm struggling with tracking which specific fields have changed during the update. Here's a simplified version of my code:
    function afterSubmit(context) {
    var accessToken = 'abcd';
    var rec = context.newRecord;
         
    try {
         if (context.type === context.UserEventType.EDIT) {
            var salesforceId = rec.getValue({ fieldId: 'custbody_salesforce_order_id' });
            log.debug("SO salesforceId", salesforceId);
            updateSalesforceOrder(accessToken, updateData, salesforceId)
            if (salesforceId) {
            updateSalesforceOrderItems(rec, accessToken, salesforceId);
            } else {
                log.error('Salesforce Order ID not found', 'Cannot update order in Salesforce without Salesforce Order ID.');
            }
        }
    } catch (e) {
        log.error('Error processing order', e.message);
    }
}

function updateSalesforceOrder(accessToken, updateData, salesforceId) {
    log.debug("updateData", updateData);
    log.debug("salesforceId", salesforceId);
    var response = https.post({
        url: 'https://xyz-ed.develop.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v61.0/sobjects/Order/' + salesforceId + '?_HttpMethod=PATCH',
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(updateData)
    });

    var responseBody = JSON.parse(response.body);
    log.debug("response--->", response);
    if (response.code === 204) {
        return {
            success: true
        };
    } else {
        log.error('Error updating order in Salesforce', responseBody);
        return {
            success: false,
            error: responseBody
        };
    }
}

function updateSalesforceOrderItems(rec, accessToken, salesforceOrderId) {
    log.debug("updateSalesforceOrderItems function called", {
        recId: rec.id,
        salesforceOrderId: salesforceOrderId
    });

    // Fetch existing order items from Salesforce
    var existingItems = getSalesforceOrderItems(accessToken, salesforceOrderId);
    log.debug("existingItems", existingItems);

    if (!existingItems.success) {
        log.error('Error fetching Salesforce order items', existingItems.error);
        return;
    }

    var existingItemRecords = existingItems.records;
    log.debug("existingItemRecords", existingItemRecords);

    // Prepare to process NetSuite order items
    var itemCount = rec.getLineCount({ sublistId: 'item' });
    log.debug("itemCount", itemCount);

    for (var i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
        var itemId = rec.getSublistValue({ sublistId: 'item', fieldId: 'item', line: i });
        var quantity = rec.getSublistValue({ sublistId: 'item', fieldId: 'quantity', line: i });
        var rate = rec.getSublistValue({ sublistId: 'item', fieldId: 'rate', line: i });

        log.debug("Processing Item", {
            itemId: itemId,
            quantity: quantity,
            rate: rate
        });

        var salesforceProductId = getSalesforceProductId(itemId);
        log.debug("salesforceProductId-->", salesforceProductId);

        var priceBookEntryId = getpriceBookProductId(accessToken, salesforceProductId);
        log.debug("priceBookEntryId", priceBookEntryId);
        var pbid = priceBookEntryId.records[0].Id;
        log.debug("pbid", pbid);

        if (salesforceProductId) {
            var orderItemData = {
                Quantity: quantity,
                UnitPrice: rate
            };
            log.debug("orderItemData", orderItemData);

            var itemFound = false;
            for (var j = 0; j < existingItemRecords.length; j++) {
                if (existingItemRecords[j].Product2Id === salesforceProductId) {
                    // Update existing item
                    var existingItemId = existingItemRecords[j].Id;
                    log.debug("Updating item", existingItemId);

                    var response = https.post({
                        url: 'https://xyz-ed.develop.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v61.0/sobjects/OrderItem/' + existingItemId + '?_HttpMethod=PATCH',
                        headers: {
                            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                        },
                        body: JSON.stringify(orderItemData)
                    });

                    log.debug("Response code", response.code);
                    log.debug("Response body", response.body);

                    if (response.code === 204) {
                        log.debug('Salesforce Order Item Updated', existingItemId);
                    } else {
                        var responseBody = JSON.parse(response.body);
                        log.error('Error updating order item in Salesforce', responseBody);
                    }

                    itemFound = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!itemFound) {
                // Create new item
                var newOrderItemData = {
                    OrderId: salesforceOrderId,
                    Product2Id: salesforceProductId,
                    PricebookEntryId: pbid,
                    Quantity: quantity,
                    UnitPrice: rate
                };
                log.debug("Creating new item", salesforceProductId);

                var response = https.post({
                    url: 'https://xyz-ed.develop.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v61.0/sobjects/OrderItem/',
                    headers: {
                        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(newOrderItemData)
                });

                log.debug("Response code", response.code);
                log.debug("Response body", response.body);

                if (response.code === 201) {
                    var responseBody = JSON.parse(response.body);
                    log.debug('Salesforce Order Item Created', responseBody.id);
                } else {
                    var responseBody = JSON.parse(response.body);
                    log.error('Error creating order item in Salesforce', responseBody);
                }
            }
        } else {
            log.error('Salesforce Product ID not found', 'Cannot process order item without Salesforce Product ID.');
        }
    }

    
}

function getSalesforceOrderItems(accessToken, salesforceOrderId) {
    var response = https.get({
        url: 'https://xyzxyz-ed.develop.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v61.0/query/?q=SELECT+Id,+Product2Id+FROM+OrderItem+WHERE+OrderId=\'' + salesforceOrderId + '\'',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
        }
    });

}


If you have a limited set of fields to check you can make use of the old record. Rough idea below:
    function afterSubmit(context) {
        const oldRec = context.oldRecord;
        const newRec = context.newRecord;
        const updateSpec = getBodyChanges(newRec, oldRec);
        updateSpec.lines = [];
        // similar idea for lines but you also have to make sure lines (checking lineuniqekey) have not been removed.
        getLineChanges(updateSpec, newRec, oldRec);
        if(!updateSpec.anyChanged){
            // no fields of interest were changed
            return;
        }
        // proceed with SalesForce update
    }

function getBodyChanges(newRec, oldRec){
    const updateSpec = {
        anyChanged: false,
        fields : {}
    };
    const bodyValueFields = ['tranid', 'memo', ...];
    const bodyTextFields = ['location', 'department'...];
    const cmpVals = (fld)=>{
        if(!oldRec) return true;
        return oldRec.getValue({fieldId:fld}) === newRec.getValue({fieldId:fld});
    };

    bodyValueFields.forEach(f=>{
        if(!cmpVals(f)) return;
        updateSpec.anyChanged = true;
        updateSpec.fields[f] = newRec.getValue({fieldId:f});
    });
    bodyTextFields.forEach(f=>{
        if(!cmpVals(f)) return; // don't need to compare texts to detect a change
        updateSpec.anyChanged = true;
        updateSpec.fields[f] = newRec.getText({fieldId:f});
    });
  }


Thanks @bknights! That can be useful but is there any other way to track changes across unlimited fields in NetSuite when syncing to salesforce?

Neither system has unlimited fields and there is no guarantee that fields are named the same or follow the same structure between the two so you are always going to have a dictionary or translation table of some sort.

There are ways however - you could cache a JSON representation of the record in the before load and then pull it and compare in the after submit but the difference in field structure and ignoring internal management fields means you still have to manage a mapping.
